# Python accessing column named 'True' or 'False' from dataframe generated by groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is generated from another dataframe by performing groupby operation using one column from the original df and another one a true/false vector generated again from a column of original df. Following code should reproduce that

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'group1': list('AABBCCAABBCC'),'group2':list('ZYYXYXXYZXYZ'),'group3':list('MMMNNNOOOMNO'),'group4':list('EFGGFEEFGGFE')})
df['check_for_A']=df['group1']=='A' #True/False vector
truth_table=df.groupby(['group1','check_for_A']).group2.count().unstack().fillna(0)
truth_table['random_values']=np.random.rand(3)
```

The output looks like this

```
 check_for_A  False  True  random_values
 group1                                 
 A                0     4       0.917167
 B                4     0       0.965026
 C                4     0       0.046257
```

My problem is while I can access the column random_values by just typing `truth_table['random_values']` , I cannot seem to access `True` or `False` columns. The command `truth_table['True']` gives an error complaining something about the name `True`. Same thing happens with `False`. I a not sure why.

I think the problem IS with True/False name because if I do something like this

```
truth_table=df.groupby(['group1','group2']).group2.count().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Column names are `x`, `y` and `z` and I do not have any problems in accessing it.

I would appreciate if someone can explain this behavior and suggest alternative solution. I am thinking changing the column names but want to find out here what I am missing anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your data using `truth_table[True]` and `truth_table[False]` without the quotes. This can be seen if you do

```
print truth_table.columns
# Index([False, True, u'random_values'], dtype='object', name=u'check_for_A')
```

This behavior comes from the fact that the values in `df['check_for_A']` are boolean and not strings.

Comment: Maybe you can add to answer `print truth_table.columns` is `Index([False, True, u'random_values'], dtype='object', name=u'check_for_A')`

Comment: Thanks @JulienSpronck and Jezrael. This was trivial but immensely helpful. Also, will help me watch out for strings/booleans in future.